# How to operate a device through fiber?

Tags: usb, ethernet, conversion, fiber

I'd like to run a webcam or a thumb drive or an external hard drive (with it's own power supply) over fiber. I thought to use the following design

[image]

or also to add a switch in case I'd like to add more devices
[image]

Would it work or there won't be enough power through the fiber for a camera/usb thumb drive/mouse/keyboard to work?

Comment: There are so many problems with this. Can I ask why?

Comment: @HackSlash That's a pretty rude, and unhelpful manner in which to ask an otherwise relevant question.

Comment: @HackSlash, this is a task that I need to solve. It should work over fiber. If you have any suggestions what should be changed or added I'll be glad to hear. But, it should be through fiber.

Comment: Anything that works over Ethernet can work over fiber. The question remains: "Why?" I ask because maybe it doesn't need to go through fiber. I'm wondering what makes you think that is a requirement.

Comment: the requirement comes from a client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it work?

No

Firstly USB Ethernet adapters are for connecting a computer to a network, not for connecting a device to a network. Probablly your best bet would be to look for Ethernet cameras.

Secondly Fiber does not carry power. Any equipment at the remote end will need to be seperately powered.

---

> if I'll replace the usb-to-ethernet converters to this set (...) which has it's own power supply, will it work over fiber?

Probablly not.

I strongly suspect that despite the mention of "Ethernet" in the title that the device is not a true Ethernet device but merely an extender that uses the same types of cabling as Ethernet. A real Ethernet device would almost certainly mention what speeds of Ethernet it supports.

True USB over Ethernet soloutions do exist but they are tricky to find (cutting through the bullshit adverts is a PITA) and may have performance issues.

There also exist dedicated USB over fiber products. If you really have to use a USB device over fiber these are likely your best option but they seem to be rather expensive.

Comment: so, assuming that the camera is seperately powered it should work, right?

Comment: No, trying to use a USB to ethernet adapter like that with a USB device will not work.

Comment: You can use USB over IP but it would be really slow, which means the fiber doesn't help you at all. https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833139028&cm_re=USB_over_IP-_-33-139-028-_-Product

Comment: @HackSlash, if I'll replace the usb-to-ethernet converters to this set (https://www.amazon.com/WEme-Extender-Connection-Extension-Speakerphone/dp/B01MRL2SK1/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1516407333&sr=8-8&keywords=RJ45%20USB%202.0)  which has it's own power supply, will it work over fiber?

Comment: @plugwash, you mean that it won't work since usb-to-ethernet is not active converter? If it had it's own power supply, like this one (amazon.com/WEme-Extender-Connection-Extension-Speakerphone/‌​dp/…), it would work, right?

Comment: @plugwash explaining the difference between USB host and USB device would make this answer more useful.

Comment: @theateist The extender you posted doesn't say anything about using IP packets. It might just be using USB protocols over the Ethernet wires. The device I posted actually hosts a USB device over IP protocols. You need to use internet protocols if you want to transmit across a network, be it made of copper or fiber. The layer one material is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @plugwash, what I don't understand is the following: assuming the device has its own power and I'm talking about my first image, why it should have any ip packets? For example, a camera/keyboard/mouse sends electrical signal through usb plug. I connect it to a usb-rj45 converter. It just remaps the wires from usb connector to rj45. Then it goes to rj45-to-fiber converter. It just translates the electrical signal on the rj45 wires to light. And then it converts it back from light to rj45. And then rj45-to-usb remaps the wiring from rj45 plug to usb plug which goes to server.

Comment: I have found this device (https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Gigabit-Device-Server-USB1000IP/dp/B004ZMYCRG/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1517503663&sr=8-5&keywords=usb+over+ip) and it worked. You were right, ethernet-to-fiber was expecting ethernet packets and since usb-to-rj45 just "remaps" the wires it still trasmits "usb codes" and not thernet packets. So ethernet-to-fiber converter didn't respond to those "codes".